# Función que devuelva True si es vocal y de lo contrario False

Tags: python

Es un ejercicio, estoy tratando de que un usuario coloque una letra, si es una vocal, será `True`, de lo contrario, será `False`, lo he escrito pero tanto si se coloca una vocal o una consonante, me sale `False`:

```
es_vocal=input("introduce una letra por favor: ")

def es_vocal ():

    if es_vocal == "a" or es_vocal == "e" or es_vocal == "i" or es_vocal == "o" or es_vocal == "u":

    print(True)

    elif es_vocal == "A" or es_vocal == "E" or es_vocal == "I" or es_vocal == "O" or es_vocal == "U":
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

es_vocal()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que *usas el mismo nombre para la variable a la que le asignas el retorno de `input` y para la función*. Como la definición de la función es posterior a la de la variable, el identificador al final apunta a la función no a la cadena. Esto ocasiona que dentro de la función `es_vocal` hace referencia a la propia función no a la cadena ingresada mediante el `input`:

```
>>> es_vocal = input("introduce una letra por favor: ")

>>> def es_vocal ():
        print(es_vocal)
>>> es_vocal()
<function es_vocal at 0x0000020060BE9E18>
```

No uses por tanto el mismo nombre, además lo normal es hacer que la función tome como argumento la cadena y retorne `True` o `False`, siguendo tu misma lógica:

```
def es_vocal (c):
    if c == "a" or c == "e" or c == "i" or c == "o" or c== "u":
        return True

    elif c == "A" or c == "E" or c == "I" or c == "O" or c == "U":
        return True

    return False

caracter = input("introduce una letra por favor: ")
print(es_vocal(caracter))
```

Comment: Por cierto, me percaté que no se coloca el else y aun así funciona, no es necesario porque es redundante ?

Comment: @Japc no es necesario porque en el momento que se ejecuta un estamento `return` (del `if` o del `elif` anterior) la función termina por lo que, a diferencia de lo que ocurre con `print`, el último `return` no se llega a ejecutar si se cumple  alguna de las condiciones previas ya que la función termina antes de llegar a él. **No hay problema alguno en que coloques el `else` si por legibilidad lo crees conveniente**, la eficiencia de ambos códigos no difiere.

Comment: Por tanto lo anterior es más una cuestión de estilo en realidad, hay guías que defienden que una función solo debe tener un `return` siempre, derivado del famoso "Single Entry, Single Exit" del los 70s, en este caso deberías  una variable local que es la que vas a retornar al final y que será `True` o `False` en función de su paso por el condicional. Por norma general  y especialmente  en funciones largas con `return` en muy diferentes lugares es buena práctica, en casos como este (y las llamadas "guard clauses") yo prefiero usar varios `return`, lo ve más legible..

Comment: Hay muchas formas válidas de implementar esta función, pero he querido solo mostrar cual era el error en tu código y no tocar demasiado tu idea inicial, por ejemplo por poder puedes reducir tu función a solo esta línea : `return c == "a" or c == "e" or c == "i" or c == "o" or c== "u" or c == "A" or c == "E" or c == "I" or c == "O" or c == "U"`

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por ayudarme a aumentar mis conocimientos en el lenguaje, es de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
def es_vocal(letra):
  return letra.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

Ejemplo:

```
letra = input('Introduce una letra por favor: ')
if es_vocal(letra):
  print('Es vocal!')
else:
  print('No es vocal!')
```

Claro que no estoy tratando la información ingresada.

Comment: Me sirvió, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La variable y la función tienen el mismo nombre

```
#primero pedimos que el usuario introduzca una letra
letra = input('Introduce una letra por favor')

#definimos la función que determinará si es una vocal
def es_vocal(letra):
    if letra.casefold() in 'aeiou': 
        # en caso de querer vocales acentuadas agregar a la cadena áéíóúàèìòùäëïöü
        # y cualquier otra letra acentuada que consideremos oportuna
        print('Es una vocal')
    else:
        print('No es vocal')

es_vocal(letra)
```

Si además queremos asegurarnos de que el usuario introduzca una sola letra podemos comprobarlo con len(letra)